# sendEmail function in Google App Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Mail on Google Spreadsheets using Google Apps Script.
I have a spreadsheet with emailAddress and Message to be sent. The Email addresses are repetitive and hence multiple mails are sent when I use the following code to the same person,

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

I need to sort the emailAddress and concatenate all the message into one and I want to send **one mail** with all the messages for a particular emailAddress instead of sending multiple mails to the same emailAddress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do as you suggest: read the entire sheet, sort it in-memory, process the repeated row blocks and send a single email per block.